# Protobuf: how to describe Option[Timestamp] in proto

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

How to describe `Option[Timestamp]` in the `*.proto` file for the following case class:

```
case class User(name: String, created: Option[Timestamp] = None)
```

`*.proto` contains:

```
   message User {
     string name = 1;
     how_to_describe_type_of_timestamp created = 2; // ???
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using "proto3" (since there is no `required` or `optional` on `name`), in which case: *everything* is optional; perhaps simply:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
message User {
     string name = 1;
     .google.protobuf.Timestamp created = 2;
}
```

If this was "proto2", then presumably:

```
syntax = "proto2";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
message User {
     required string name = 1;
     optional .google.protobuf.Timestamp created = 2;
}
```